# doubts as to receive a variable via the post rest with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've researched on various websites and got the solution below but still can not make it work, someone has any idea what might be doing wrong?

I use the http://hurl.it/ to test my server but when i try get nameArea from post nothing come
myserver:8080/area/nameArea=area1&area1x=-30.02724579591031&area1y=-51.22842527925968

```
var app   = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");


app.post('/area',function(req,res){
var Areanome = req.body.nomearea;
var Area1x = req.body.area1x;
    var Area1y = req.body.area1y;

    console.log ('Read name area: '+Areanome);

    console.log(geometry);
var data = {
    "error":1,
    "Area":""
};
```

but in log only comes this Read name area:undefined
i don't get what i'm doing wrong :(
if I try
        console.log ('test: '+ JSON.stringify(req.body));
come this:
       {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the data on the request body, but in the post you are sending it on the request query strings.

The values you want will be found on:

```
req.query
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your route, should it not be:

```
 myserver:8080/area?nameArea=area1&area1x=-30.02724579591031&area1y=-51.22842527925968
```

Notice `?` instead of your `&`.

Secondly, you are checking the body, but should be checking the query.

```
req.query
```